Is AppsFlyer devkey a private or public key?
I can't seem to find this specific information in AppsFlyer documentation, it says here:

AppsFlyer uses the dev key to uniquely identify your account. The dev key is mandatory because it allows the SDK to securely send and retrieve data that belongs to your account. Your developer should install and integrate the SDK, and embed the dev key.

I want to know whether it's okay to embed the devkey inside client side javascript; rather than grabbing the key from an env variable during SDK initialisation..
What would be the security risk (if there is) to expose your AppsFlyer devkey to public?

have you found any information on this issue?
